# Best way to handle a transaction between Firebase Authentication and Database realtime

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When a new user account is created successfully, using Firebase Authentication, I try to make a second request to create his profile (name, email and phone) in the Firebase Database, but if the second request fails I will have an user without a profile and this case shouldn't be possible, as he will not be able to edit his profile when he is logged in, so currently I'm deleting this recently created user in Firebase Auth, to allow him retry the creation, but it does not solve the problem as the delete request can also fail. What's the best way of handling transaction in Firebase, having both the user and his profile created successfully or none of them?

```
 private void attemptToCreateAccount(final Credentials cred) {
        getCompositeDisposable().add(
                getAuthService().createAccount(cred)
                        .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                        .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                        .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<User>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(User user) {
                                 addUserProfileToDatabase(user.getEmail(), user.getUserUid(), cred.getUsername(), cred.getPassword());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                getView().showMessage(e.toString());
                            }
                        })
        );
    }

--------------------------

 private void addUserProfileToDatabase(final String email, final String userUid, final String name, final String password) {
        final Profile profile = new Profile("", "", "", email, "", name);
        getCompositeDisposable().add(
                getDatabaseSource().createNewProfileToUser(userUid, profile)
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver(){
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        getView().saveUserData(userUid, email, name);
                        getView().goToProfilePageActivity();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        // TODO RETRY OPERATION OR DELETE THE CURRENT CREATED USER
                        getView().showMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        deleteUserCreatedWithoutProfile(email, password);
                    }
                })
        );
    }

    --------------------------

private void deleteUserCreatedWithoutProfile(String email, String password){
        getCompositeDisposable().add(
                getDatabaseSource().deleteUser(email, password)
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver(){

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.e("FIREBASE", "user deleted because profile could not be created successfully");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e("FIREBASE", "Houston We have a problem. User was created without a profile.");
                    }
                })
        );
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no need of FirebaseDatabase you can store user information firebaseAuth also here how you can do

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
        .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```

for more go to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

Comment: I didn't use FirebaseAuth because I may need to save some information that is not present on it by default, like phoneNumber and CellPhoneNumber